# Error en consulta con Query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
$infohdv = DB::select('SELECT aspirantes.nombres_asp, 
aspirantes.apellidos_asp, aspirantes.edad_asp, departamentos.nom_dep, 
municipios.nom_mun, experiencias_laborales.car_exp_lab, 
empleos_laborales.nom_emp_lab, 
GROUP_CONCAT(conocimientos_habilidades.nom_con_hab) as nom_con_hab FROM 
aspirantes LEFT JOIN paises ON paises.id_pais = aspirantes.id_pais_asp INNER 
JOIN departamentos ON departamentos.id_dep = aspirantes.dep_res_asp INNER 
JOIN municipios on municipios.id_mun = aspirantes.mun_res_asp INNER JOIN 
formaciones_academicas on formaciones_academicas.id_asp_for_aca = 
aspirantes.id_asp INNER JOIN experiencias_laborales ON 
experiencias_laborales.id_asp_exp_lab = aspirantes.id_asp LEFT JOIN 
empleos_laborales on empleos_laborales.id_emp_lab = 
experiencias_laborales.car_asp_emp_lab INNER JOIN conocimientos_habilidades 
on conocimientos_habilidades.id_asp_con_hab = aspirantes.id_asp');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que estoy haciendo es seleccionar información especifica y también estoy concatenando solo una columna de nombre "nom_con_hab" la cual contiene varios nombres pero me da error.

En MySQL la consulta si me sale correctamente asi, con el resultado que busco en la columna "nom_con_hab".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es que no puedes usar funciones de agregación como `GROUP_CONCAT()` sin usar `GROUP BY`. Me extraña que te funcione en PHPMyAdmin... ¿?

Comment: Si use el GROUP BY pero no me da el resultado de concatenación que necesito en la columna nom_con_lab :/ ¿podrían colaborarme?